# What is causing this emscripten build to fail?

Tags: makefile, emscripten

I am using the following cmd to build a wasm using emscripten:

```
npm run build
```

It gets so far through before failing during the configure:

```
configure: make -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/usr/share/emscripten/cmake/Modules/Platform/Emscripten.cmake -DCMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING_EMULATOR=/usr/bin/node;--experimental-wasm-threads
make: invalid option -- 'D'
make: invalid option -- 'D'
```

Producing a final error:

```
This program built for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu

Report bugs to <bug-make@gnu.org>

emcmake: error: 'make -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/usr/share/emscripten/cmake/Modules/Platform/Emscripten.cmake -DCMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING_EMULATOR=/usr/bin/node;--experimental-wasm-threads' failed (returned 2)

make: *** [Makefile:84: build/popt/.libs/libpopt.a] Error 1
```

What is going wrong?

Update using cmake instead of make produces this error:

```
configure: cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/home/user1/Downloads/emsdk/upstream/emscripten/cmake/Modules/Platform/Emscripten.cmake -DCMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING_EMULATOR=/home/user1/Downloads/emsdk/node/14.18.2_64bit/bin/node;--experimental-wasm-threads

CMake Warning:
No source or binary directory provided.  Both will be assumed to be the same as the current working directory, but note that this warning will become a fatal error in future CMake releases.

CMake Error: The source directory "/home/user1/Downloads/test1.js-master/build/popt" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.

Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI.

emcmake: error: 'cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/home/user1/Downloads/emsdk/upstream/emscripten/cmake/Modules/Platform/Emscripten.cmake -DCMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING_EMULATOR=/home/user1/Downloads/emsdk/node/14.18.2_64bit/bin/node;--experimental-wasm-threads' failed (returned 1)

make: *** [Makefile:84: build/popt/.libs/libpopt.a] Error 1
```

Comment: Well, just as the message says, the `-D` option is not a valid option for the `make` program.  To me it looks like you want to be using `cmake` here, not `make`

Comment: I updated the Makefile to use cmake instead and now the above error.